# Convert Delimited Test File to JSON Object Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, fs

```
fs.readFile('data.txt', 'utf8', (err, result)=>{
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  else{
    console.log(result);
  }
})
```

The above code is working fine. But I want to parse the result as a JSON object.

**Format of Test File**

```
test1:value1:"Pass":John:"Log1"

test2:value2:"Fail":Peter:"Log2"

test3:value3:"Pass":Peter:"Log3"
```

**Format of result variable**

```
test1:value1:"Pass":John:"Log1"

test2:value2:"Fail":Peter:"Log2"

test3:value3:"Pass":Peter:"Log3"
```

***Now I want to convert the result to a JSON object.***

```
[
 {
   "test": "test1",
   "value": "value1",
   "status": "Pass",
   "name": "John",
   "log": "Log1"
 },
 {
   "test": "test2",
   "value": "value2",
   "status": "Fail",
   "name": "Peter",
   "log": "Log2"
 },
 {
   "test": "test3",
   "value": "value3",
   "status": "Pass",
   "name": "Peter",
   "log": "Log3"
 }
]
```

**Please note. I also want to use result so I need to process after getting value of result**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you need an array of objects or its JSON string representation, so these are both results:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('data.txt', 'utf8', (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(result);

    const array = result.split(/(?<=.)[\r\n]+(?=.)/u).map((line) => {
      const values = line.trim().split(/\s*:\s*/u)
                     .map(value => value.replace(/^"|"$/gu, ''));
      const keys = ['test', 'value', 'status', 'name', 'log'];
      return Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key, index) => [key, values[index]]));
    });
    console.log(array);

    const json = JSON.stringify(array, null, '  ');
    console.log(json);
  }
});
```

Comment: How can I push this JSON data into a MySQL table with keys as column headers?

Comment: @UtkrishtAgrawal Sorry, I do not know MySQL. It is worth ascking a new question.